# Problem with the StreamBuilder documentSnapshot

Tags: flutter

Here there is some problem with the streambuilder .. it seems to work just well and returns the user name as needed but there is always an error shown in the debug console.

═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: 
The relevant error-causing widget was
    StreamBuilder

```
class UpdateForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdateFormState createState() => _UpdateFormState();
}

class _UpdateFormState extends State<UpdateForm> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  // form values
  String _currentName;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);

return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Update your settings.',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                      stream: Firestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .document(user.uid)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                        _currentName = snapshot.data['name'];
                        return Text(snapshot.data['name']);
                      }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an example of how I use `StreamBuilder` make sure you are using this setup on both `StreamBuilders`. Also you have nested `StreamBuilder` but the `AsyncSnapshots` are named the same try giving them different names like `snapshot` and `asyncSnapshot`

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Test').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> asyncSnapshot) {
            if (asyncSnapshot.hasData) {
              List<DocumentChange> snapshot =
                  asyncSnapshot.data.documentChanges;
              snapshot.forEach((DocumentChange change) {
                _test.add(
                  Test(
                    name: change.document.data['name'],
                    value: change.document.data['value'],
                  ),
                );
              });
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _test.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(_test[index].name),
                        Text(_test[index].value.toString())
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            } else if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('There was an error...');
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
```

Comment: no problem if you have any more questions id be glad to help just let me know

Answer (score 4):

Well the problem is in second stream builder. You are not checking if you stream has data. So for the first time your stream is empty which causes the error and as soon as the data comes from the stream, `StreamBuilder` re-renders itself hiding the error from the first time. You are checking for the `hasData` for the first `StreamBuilder`.

Simply check if stream has data if not return a loader for the time being.

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
             .collection('users')
             .document(user.uid)
             .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        _currentName = snapshot.data['name'];
                        return Text(snapshot.data['name']);
                    }
                    //this will load first
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
```

Comment: i did the if check and it solved the problem.. thank you so much..

Comment: @alex seems like this one already has an accepted answer. What about it ?

Comment: I have accepted the answer because that is working alright on the emulator of this person who answered it..but i'm having problems with it on my simulator. I'll create a new question it you can help out with it..

Comment: Rule of thumb my friend. Never accepts an answer until it solves your problem to let others know that question still needs a solution,

Comment: @AliHussam this is the best solution, works flawlessly!